# Changing the position of the React mention suggestion List

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using `react-mentions` in my project for mentioning users.. The problem is My comment input is at bottom of the page.. The `react-mentions` show the suggestion when we type `@` in the bottom of the cursor. I want this list to be above the cursor...Can anyone help me?

I tried Editing the css, but my methods doesn't work.
This is the Css i am using

```
.mentions {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.mentions--singleLine .mentions__control {
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 130px; */
}
.mentions--singleLine .mentions__highlighter {
  /* padding: 1px; */
  border: 2px inset transparent;
}
.mentions--singleLine .mentions__input {
  /* padding: 1px; */
  border: 2px inset;
}

.mentions--multiLine .mentions__control {
  font-family: monospace;
  /* font-size: 14pt; */
}
.mentions--multiLine .mentions__highlighter {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  /* padding: 5px; */
  /* min-height: 63px; */
}
.mentions--multiLine .mentions__input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  /* padding: 9px; */
  outline: 0;
}

.mentions__suggestions{
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}

.mentions__suggestions__list {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  /* font-size: 10pt; */
}

.mentions__suggestions__item {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.mentions__suggestions__item--focused {
  background-color: #cee4e5;
}

.mentions__mention {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: blue;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white, 1px -1px 1px white, -1px 1px 1px white,
    -1px -1px 1px white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This is the js code

```
<MentionsInput className="mentions" value={newComment} onChange={e => setNewComment(e.target.value)} >
                <Mention
                  trigger="@"
                  data={tagUserList}
                />
              </MentionsInput>
```

But the output is still like the same..The list is showing below the cursor
Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forceSuggestionsAboveCursor={true}`

```
<MentionsInput
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          style={defaultStyle}
          placeholder={"Mention people using '@'"}
          suggestionsPortalHost={container}
          forceSuggestionsAboveCursor={true}
        >
    <Mention data={data} onAdd={onAdd} style={defaultMentionStyle} />
 </MentionsInput>
```

There is a [demo page](https://react-mentions.vercel.app/) that shows how it works.
This code example can be found in their GitHub [here](https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions/blob/master/demo/src/examples/BottomGuard.js)

It's the middle one from BottomGuard's section.

You can also use `allowSuggestionsAboveCursor={true}`, which will use bottom only if there's space.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable suggestion.. I didnt saw the bottomGuard example of their..Thank you so much...

Comment: You are welcome. Hope we also help future searchers :)

Comment: for me it doesn't work, i need to change the position of suggestions

Comment: I recommend opening a new question for your case